# Pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is upper semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

M is a metric space. I want to prove that if $f:M \rightarrow R$ and there is a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ such that $\forall x \in M$, $f_n(x) \downarrow f(x)$, then $f$ is upper semicontinuous. I've been struggling with it for a while. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is upper-semicontinuous *if and only if* for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x : f(x) < \alpha\}$ is open. But $\{x : f(x) < \alpha\} = \cup_{n}\{x : f_n(x)<\alpha\}$. Because $f_n$ are continuous, we have that $\{x : f_n(x)<\alpha\}$ is open for every $n$, therefore yielding that $\{x : f(x) < \alpha\}$ as a union of open sets is open.